# Key Press shortcuts in WP8

Tags: 8.0

Standard external keys provided by Windows Phone 8.0 are Volume down, Volume up, Power and Camera. Is there anyone have the list of external key press shortcuts (like soft reset)?

Answer (score 3):

**Soft Reset**:

Power + Volume Down ▼ for 10 seconds

**Screenshot**:

(WP7.5/WP8) Power + Start Button

(WP8.1) Power + Volume Up

Comment: I think there's some more shortcuts with Volume Up and so.

Comment: @NK If you can think of them, then please edit this answer or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot is now Volume up + power. Hard Reset is Volume Down + Power + Camera