# How to change thumbnail image in OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, photos

How do I change the photo on the thumbnail for OneDrive folders on my Lumia 520?

Comment: I assume you want to change the Image of the Live Tile?

Comment: Yes the Live Tile in the Onedrive folder in the online photo section.  The images are stuck on photo long deleted and I would love to update them.

Comment: have you tried doing a soft reset? http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/key-press-shortcuts-in-wp8

Comment: Have you gone into that folder in the OneDrive app, and refreshed the contents? did you delete the offending photo from the phone, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Use the storage sense app, then phone, then temp files.  Delete the temp files (do it several times).  Then the thumbnail will be reset to something more current.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can simply create an image called `Folder` and place it in the folder. The thumbnail will then be whatever the image is.